# Get a textblock value in a listbox using GestureServices

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Sorry guys, I had asked this question earlier but could not figure out the answer. Made an edit to see if that bumps it, but that did not seem to work. So here is the last try to the question

I can't seem to figure out how one can get the value of a specific textblock in a listbox. To start things off, here is the code:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listItems" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="210" >
            <Grid Height="210" Background="#75FFF8DC">

               <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                  <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap"
                     DoubleTap="GestureListener_DoubleTap"
                     Hold="GestureListener_Hold"
                     Flick="GestureListener_Flick"/>
               </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener> 

                     ...CODE... 
</></></>...
```

The code area contains a bunch of other grids, partitions (columns and rows) and textblocks. Here is an example:

```
<Image Name="XXX" Source="{Binding XXXPath}" Stretch="Fill" 
   Grid.Column="0"/>
<TextBlock Name="YYY" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  
   Text="{Binding YYYPath}" Foreground="Black"/>
<TextBlock Name="ZZZ" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  
   Text="{Binding ZZZPath}" Foreground="Black"/>
```

So what I want, is if someone taps the grid (that means anything in the grid, including these textblocks and images), I want to first get the text of the textblock "YYY."

I could have inserted that code into a textblock and used sender as textblock, but I do not want to limit my gestures to one textblock, nor do I want to repeat that for each element in the grid (lots of issues and seems unnecessary).

Edit: If this does not work, I can also implement just one tap gesture (but again, for the whole grid) and use that to get the value of the textblock. Is there no way? Otherwise I will have to do this: Add tap for the textblock and use sender as a textblock, then get the value of the text. But I really do **not** want to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use bindings for your textblocks and image. So why don't you use ( if you haven't already done it) an `IList` instance of class which hold an information about them? Then set this instance as an `ItemSource` for your listbox. That way when user taps somewhere on listbox you can catch the `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` of a listbox item. And this will help you to figure out which element of IList collection to extract so you could get your text or image or whatever you need.

And you don't need to use **GestureServices** from external `Silverlight Toolkit` with Mango. `Tap`, `DoubleTap` etc. are built-in.

Comment: I'll try that sometime today and get back. Does it also include actions such as Flick, etc.? That's the only reason I'm using GestureServices.

Comment: Yes but if you will use `XNA` libs in project. And I guess it has to be detected from code not `XAMl`. Better keep going with `Silverlight Toolkit` then.

Comment: Aah, haven't managed to work on it today. But don't worry, if it works by tomorrow, you'll get your up-vote and correct answer :)